# Approximate discrete Laplacian with continuous Laplacian

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, spectral-graph-theory

In various papers I've been reading, the authors embed a graph in a manifold, then claim that one can approximate the discrete Laplacian with the continuous Laplacian by expanding the continuous Laplace operator up to whatever order. Then, the spectra are supposed to converge asymptotically.

Though intuitively obvious as the graph grows and the relative distance between points shrinks, I would like to see a proof and an estimate of the associated error. None of the authors cite a source, so my guess is that this must be well known.

Comment: This will be treated in books on numerical methods for pdes, I do not recall seeing it discussed a graph theory text.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil Thanks. I looked at one last night and it was mostly about the finite element method, which provided enough of an idea. I guess the key bit that I was missing was cancelling $\epsilon$ in the denominator of with other constants.

Do you have a particular reference you like best?

Comment: Could you please add a couple of references as examples of such arguments? I might be able to give some hints for working out a proof.